# Memory management in java when running sql in a loop

Tags: java, memory

I have been facing some trouble with memory management. I have some code here that runs an sql query in a loop, puts the data into Array Lists and then does some computations. I have run many similar programs before without this problem. The reason I put the query in a loop was so that too much memory wouldn't be stored in java objects at once. However, now when I run the program, I get a memory error at the exact same place every time (when it is at the 29th iteration of the loop).

Here is the error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.grow(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
at transnMat.bootTrnsn.main(bootTrnsn.java:82)
```

I have pasted the code below, I'd really appreciate any tips on what I might change to get rid of this -

```
Connection conn = null;Statement st = null;ResultSet rstru = null;
for(int i=start;i<stop;i++) {
    double[][] forvariance = new double[(demos.length-1)][numsims];
    ArrayList<Long> hhids1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Double> outlierwt = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> fbdemos = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> trudemos = new ArrayList<>();
    rstru = st.executeQuery(
        "select TRUTH_DEMO_ID, FB_DEMO_ID, RN_ID, OUTLIER_WEIGHT from SCRATCH.." +
        months + "monthtable where BRAND_ID = " + brands[i] +
        " order by RN_ID");
    while (rstru.next()) { //Get query results and put them into a hash map.
        String temp0 = rstru.getString(1);
        String temp1 = rstru.getString(2);
        String temp2 = rstru.getString(3);
        String temp3 = rstru.getString(4);
        //String temp5 = rstru.getString(6);
        hhids1.add(Long.parseLong(temp2.substring(0,11)));
        fbdemos.add(temp1);
        trudemos.add(temp0);
        outlierwt.add(Double.parseDouble(temp3));
    }
    for(int sim=0;sim<numsims;sim++) {
        trnsnpv = new double[demos.length][demos.length-1];
        HashMap<Long,Integer> thissampl = bootsampl2.get(sim);
        for(int i1=0;i1<fbdemos.size();i1++) {
            if(thissampl.containsKey(hhids1.get(i1)))
                trnsnpv[dems.get(fbdemos.get(i1))][dems.get(trudemos.get(i1))-1] +=
                    outlierwt.get(i1)*(double)thissampl.get(hhids1.get(i1));
        }
        for(int j=0;j<trnsnpv.length;j++) { //27 rows
            trnsnpv[j] = normalize(trnsnpv[j]);
            for(int k=0;k<trnsnpv[j].length;k++) { //26 columns
                forvariance[k][sim] += trnsnpv[j][k];
            }
        }
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < (demos.length - 1); k++) {
        double d = StdStats.var11(forvariance[k]);
        fileIO.fileIO.write2file(brands[i] + "," + demos[k+1] +
                "," + String.valueOf(d) + "\n", "vars.csv");
    }
    System.out.println("Brands processed: " + String.valueOf(i-start) +
            " out of: " + (stop-start));
    hhids1.clear();
    outlierwt.clear();
    fbdemos.clear();
    trudemos.clear();
}
```

Comment: Try executing your program with more heap memory.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the heap space with `-Xmx...`?  Maybe your JVM just needs more memory.

Comment: Also, you're failing at a point where it's trying to increase the size of an array backing an `ArrayList`, which more than doubles the memory requirement.  You should allocate the arraylist with enough space that it doesn't need to be increased.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the quick replies. The thing is that I have run similar programs before (on the same database) with no memory problems (and need to increase the heap size). I was indeed not using array lists before, though. The reason I am using them here is that I don't know how much data the query will return. Jim - how do I allocate space to an arraylist?

Comment: Do two queries. First select count(*), then you know. l = new ArrayList<Type>(100) will create an array list with 100 items in it. At that point, you can just use arrays, which will save you space. You also don't mention how many rows the queries are returning.

Comment: LinkedList could also help minimize the size.

Comment: Basically, you're using too much storage.  Pre-allocating the ArrayLists will maybe get you a dozen iterations farther, but it's the objects you're putting into the ArrayLists, not the ArrayLists themselves, that is eating things up.  (And a LinkedList would be worse.)  You either need more heap or less data at one bite.

Comment: (It fails on the 29th iteration because it's the 29th brand that has so many DB entries.)

Comment: Thanks, Hot Licks (and every one). You were absolutely right. I changed the code so that I wouldn't have to store those massive arrays and its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the version of the code that did work (for my own reference)..

```
for(int i=start;i<stop;i++){
            double[][] forvariance = new double[(demos.length-1)][numsims];
            trnsnpv = new double[numsims][demos.length][demos.length-1];
            int size = 0;
            Long hhids1;
            Double outlierwt;
            String fbdemos;
            String trudemos;
            rstru = st.executeQuery("select TRUTH_DEMO_ID, FB_DEMO_ID, RN_ID, OUTLIER_WEIGHT from SCRATCH.."+months+"monthtable where BRAND_ID = " + brands[i]+" order by RN_ID");
            while (rstru.next()) {//Get query results and put them into a hash map.
                String temp0 = rstru.getString(1);String temp1 = rstru.getString(2);String temp2 = rstru.getString(3);String temp3 = rstru.getString(4);
                hhids1 = (Long.parseLong(temp2.substring(0,11)));
                fbdemos = (temp1);
                trudemos = (temp0);
                outlierwt = (Double.parseDouble(temp3));
                for(int sim=0;sim<numsims;sim++){
                    HashMap<Long,Integer> thissampl = bootsampl2.get(sim);
                    if(thissampl.containsKey(hhids1))
                        trnsnpv[sim][dems.get(fbdemos)][dems.get(trudemos)-1] += outlierwt*(double)thissampl.get(hhids1);
                }
                size++;
            }
            System.out.print("Processing: " + size + " rows");
            for(int sim=0;sim<numsims;sim++){
                for(int j=0;j<trnsnpv[sim].length;j++){//27 rows
                    trnsnpv[sim][j] = normalize(trnsnpv[sim][j]);
                    for(int k=0;k<trnsnpv[sim][j].length;k++){//26 columns
                        forvariance[k][sim] += trnsnpv[sim][j][k];
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int k = 0; k < (demos.length - 1); k++){
                double d = StdStats.var11(forvariance[k]);
                fileIO.fileIO.write2file(brands[i] + "," + demos[k+1] + "," + String.valueOf(d) + "\n", "vars.csv");
            }
            System.out.print("Brands processed: " + String.valueOf(i-start + 1 ) + " out of: " + (stop-start) + "\n");
            //hhids1.clear();outlierwt.clear();fbdemos.clear();trudemos.clear();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Several performance problems here:

1. The database has to recompile the query each time because the SQL is not parameterized.  Consider the use of a prepared statement.
2. Nested loops.  I see one point where you have 4 nested loops.
3. There is no way I can figure out what your logic is doing due to the variable names and excessive looping.  If it's possible, and not sure if it is with your logic (depends on what aggregation you are doing), can you do everything one object at a time in your while (rs.next()) loop?

Ex:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    String temp0 = rstru.getString(1);
    String temp1 = rstru.getString(2);
    String temp2 = rstru.getString(3);
    String temp3 = rstru.getString(4);
    //String temp5 = rstru.getString(6);

    // do all of your work in here, so that your objects
    // can be garbage collected before the next iteration
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I didn't put every thing in the while loop, but some thing along those line.. I changed the data structures around so I didn't have to store the arrays each time and it worked.

Comment: One more thing - the nested loops are unavoidable, I think; but I'm still enough of a beginner to not understand what you mean in point 1. Can you explain "data base has to recompile the query". It is a different query each time in the loop. I've never used prepared statements before. Will that make the code faster?

Comment: The wikipedia article for prepared statements has an excellent explanation of it.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Essentially, when the database receives a query, there is a lot of analysis it does on it.  If you can put in placeholder variables, the database can re-use that work.